# Socket Exception not working in GetConnect in getx

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to get socket exception on api call i'm using getx GetConnect and GetService for Api Calling but it does not returning anything can someone help me,

```
Future<Response> postDatabyJson(uri,body)async{
try{
  print("Api Url  "+uri.toString());
  print("body "+body.toString());
  Response response=await post(uri, body,headers: _mainHeader );
  return response;
}  on SocketException{
  print('internet isssssus');
  return Response();
  // var retry=await apiDialog();
  // if(retry){
  //   var data= await postDatabyJson(uri,body,);
  //   return data;
  // }
  // else{
  //   return Response(statusCode: 0,statusText: 'Try Again...');
  // }
}


catch(e){
  return Response(statusCode: 1,statusText: e.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: You can manage connectivity Issues by using connectivity_plus Package

Answer (score 0):

add **catch** keyword after SocketException.

Ex : ***on SocketException catch(error){}***